# Scraping dynamically generated html by JavaScript with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, dynamic-html

I currently have a problem with dynamically generated html code on this side:

[http://www.economia-sniim.gob.mx/Nuevo/Home.aspx?opcion=Consultas/MercadosNacionales/PreciosDeMercado/Agricolas/ConsultaFrutasYHortalizas.aspx?SubOpcion=4|0](http://www.economia-sniim.gob.mx/Nuevo/Home.aspx?opcion=Consultas/MercadosNacionales/PreciosDeMercado/Agricolas/ConsultaFrutasYHortalizas.aspx?SubOpcion=4%7C0)

I would like to choose "Origen" and "Date" options in website, but I don't have all HTML code.

Could someone give me a hint, how to **scrape** all dynamically generated html code ?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The advantage with selenium is that you can actually start a browser session from your program and enable an event in javascript (like in this case scroll)

```
In [8]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [9]: from selenium import webdriver

In [10]: driver = webdriver.Firefox()

In [11]: driver.get('http://cavemendev.com')

In [12]: html = driver.page_source

In [13]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [14]: driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")

In [15]: for tag in soup.find_all('title'):
   ....:     print tag.text
```

Let me know if doesn't make much sense